# PHP extension_dir changes after updates

Tags: ubuntu, php

I am advising a client who is catching up on updates, and has recently updated Ubuntu from 18.04LTs to v20.04LTS along with packages. They are using the PHP 7.2 (7.2.34-38+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) that comes with Ubuntu. After the update, the memcached extension is no longer available. My impression is that this received backported security updates, and we are relying on this until the whole app is replaced later this year, and hopefully move to some managed hosting.

Looking at the configuration via phpinfo() from the web, I see:

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path /etc/php/7.2/apache2
>
> extension_dir /usr/lib/php/20170718

The contents of /usr/lib/php/20170718

```
$ ls /usr/lib/php/20170718/
calendar.so  ftp.so      mbstring.so   pdo.so        soap.so       wddx.so       zip.so
ctype.so     gd.so       mysqli.so     phar.so       sockets.so    xmlreader.so
curl.so      gettext.so  mysqlnd.so    posix.so      sysvmsg.so    xmlrpc.so
dom.so       iconv.so    newrelic.so   readline.so   sysvsem.so    xml.so
exif.so      intl.so     opcache.so    shmop.so      sysvshm.so    xmlwriter.so
fileinfo.so  json.so     pdo_mysql.so  simplexml.so  tokenizer.so  xsl.so
```

And the contents of the directory below that

```
/usr/lib/php$ ls 
20170718  20210902  7.2  8.1  packaging              php-helper              sessionclean
20190902  20220829  7.4  8.2  php-fpm-socket-helper  php-maintscript-helper
```

Seeing both the version and date api numbers seems a bit confusing here, and I am assuming there is some sort of mixup between these going on. I don't really know what the difference between them are though.

When I try to install php-memcached:

```
$ sudo apt install php-memcached
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php-memcached is already the newest version (3.2.0+2.2.0-3+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

I also noticed this when I try to run any php-cli command:

```
$ php --version
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'igbinary.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/igbinary.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/igbinary.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/igbinary.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/igbinary.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'msgpack.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/msgpack.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/msgpack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/msgpack.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/msgpack.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'memcached.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/memcached.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/memcached.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/memcached.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/memcached.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.2.34-38+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Feb 14 2023 18:27:17) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.34-38+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

So presumably it's igbinary, msgpack, and memcached that's missing.

Question is, what went wrong during the update process, and how can I install these packages correctly?

Update: Eventually I think this is what fixed it:

```
 # add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
 # sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4f4ea0aae5267a6c
 # apt-get install php-memcached php7.2-memcached
 # apt-get install php-igbinary php7.2-igbinary # probably redundant to the above
 # apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.2
 # systemctl restart apache2
```

Though I'm not sure how it broke in the first place.

Comment: What's the output of `apt info php-memcached`? Can you install a specific version with `apt install php7.2-memcached`?

Comment: @Freddy I'm thinking that I'm just not going to be able to install memcached for 7.2. The related output I think you are interested for `apt info php-memcached` is `Provides: php7.4-memcached`, so I'm trying to just upgrade to that. But that's giving me trouble as well, since I need igbinary still, and I can't seem to install that for 7.4 as that seems to only install for 8.2.

Comment: There are all kinds of versions for [igbinary 3.2.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+sourcepub/14487805/+listing-archive-extra). But since there are also php7.4 packages for Ubuntu 20.04, you should upgrade to these (before you make the jump to 8.2).